# Launch Agent with Relative Path

Tags: macos, bash

Is it possible to execute a script in the current user's home directory with a `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` agent? I current have (not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.puppies</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <true/>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/bin/sh</string>
          <string>~/script.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>3600</integer></dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Try ditching the `~` and explicitly spell out the absolute path.

Comment: @phs I wanted to make the launch agent generic. I understand it will work if I enter the full path.

Comment: Ah.  Why do you think the process user will be who you think it is?

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Use `.` instead of `~` and it should work.  plists won't understand `~` or `$HOME`.

Comment: @devnull As in `<string>~/script.sh</string>`? (That doesn't seem to be working)

Comment: @KevinSylvestre No, `<string>./script.sh</string>`

Comment: @devnul Sorry type in my typing. That still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Found a duplicate answer on the Apple Stack Exchange site:

[http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/run-bash-script-at-login-stored-in-the-home-folder][1]


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/run-bash-script-at-login-stored-in-the-home-folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set EnableGlobbing to true:

```
<key>EnableGlobbing</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>~/*</string>
</array>
```

EnableGlobbing enables expanding tildes and globs in ProgramArguments but not in Program. Tildes are expanded in WatchPaths and QueueDirectories by default.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. :)
Tried in the following Mac OS X Versions: 10.7, 10.8, and 10.9.

Comment: This no longer works as of 10.10 (you'll see _“The EnableGlobbing key is no longer respected. Please remove it.”_ in `/var/log/syslog`). See [this Ask Different answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153149/21650) for a workaround (using `bash -c`).

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use the following in OS X:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/bin/bash</string>
<string>-c</string>
<string>lb=/Users/`users`/Library;
```

So you could try replacing your tilda with:

```
/Users/`users`
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as below

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>zsh</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>/bin/sh</string>
      <string>~/script.sh</string>
    </array>
```